# `ListPlot` with colours based on 3rd dimension

Tags: plotting

If I have a list and plot it:

```
sample={{0.0758227, 2.76751, "C"}, {0.230704, 2.773, "B"}, {0.25679, 2.66845,
   "S"}};
ListPlot[sample[[All,{1,2}]]]
```

Now I would like to print each point with a colour based on the third column, say if I have an association:

```
<|"B" -> 1, "C" -> 2, "S" -> 3|>
```

then the numbers would be indices of some `ColorData`, say: `ColorData[97] /@ Range[3]`, then everything that has "B" in the last column is plotted blue, "C" is plotted orange and "S" is plotted green.

Also, I should mention that the sample above is really just a sample, the real list has on the order $10^5$ rows, however, the number of distinct letters in the last column is about 20.

I have found some answers but they deal with plotting each point with different colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];

sample = Table[
   {RandomReal[], RandomReal[5], 
    RandomSample[CharacterRange["A", "J"], 1][[1]]}, 10^5];

color = Association@Thread[CharacterRange["A", "J"] -> Range[10]];
```

[`SplitBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html) and [`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html) are used rather than [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) to control the sequencing of the categories.

```
data = SplitBy[SortBy[sample, Last], Last];

Module[{categories = (#[[1, -1]] & /@ data)},
 ListPlot[
  #[[All, 1 ;; 2]] & /@ data,
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False,
  PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97][color[#]] & /@ categories),
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[categories]]]
```

[image]

With 10^5 data points it only takes a couple of seconds; however, the data is so dense as to be meaningless unless there is some inherent structure that becomes visible.

Answer (score 2):

```
sample={{0.0758227, 2.76751, "C"}, {0.230704, 2.773, "B"}, {0.25679, 2.66845, "S"}};
assoc = <|"B" -> 1, "C" -> 2, "S" -> 3|>;

sample2 = sample /. assoc;

ListPlot[Style[{#, #2}, ColorData[97][#3], PointSize[.05]] & @@@ sample2]
```

or

```
ListPlot[List/@sample2[[All,{1,2}]], PlotStyle-> ColorData[97] /@ sample2[[All,3]])]
```

to get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Both of the above are slow for large input data. Using `Graphics` gives a faster method:

```
Graphics[{PointSize[.05], Transpose@{ColorData[97]/@sample2[[All,3]], 
 Point/@sample2[[All, {1,2}]]}}, Axes->True]
```

or

```
Graphics[{PointSize[.05], Point[sample2[[All, {1,2}]], 
  VertexColors->(ColorData[97] /@ sample2[[All,3]])]}, Axes->True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank but this is way too slow, original `ListPlot` is about 10 seconds, this has already been running for 3 minutes and nothing.

Comment: @leosenko, it **is** slow. I think using  `Graphics` would be faster.